# How to run the PowerShell command to delete a persistent stored user environment variable in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

How to run the following PowerShell command in a batch file to delete the persistent stored user environment variable `PCM_STYLE`?

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PCM_STYLE",$null,"User")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need to use PowerShell for this, you could perform the command you've shown in your question like this:

```sh
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\"PCM_STYLE\", $null, \"User\")"
```

However, it would probably be best practice to, check if it exists first, using an `If` condition:

```sh
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "If ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(\"PCM_STYLE\", \"User\")) { [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\"PCM_STYLE\", $null, \"User\") }
```

---

However, you can remove the environment variable in the registry without resorting to using PowerShell, with the aid of the `reg.exe` utility:

```sh
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Delete "HKCU\Environment" /V "PCM_STYLE" /F
```

And, as before, it would probably be best practice to determine if it exists first, *(also using reg.exe)*:

```sh
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query "HKCU\Environment" /V "PCM_STYLE" 1>NUL 2>&1 && ( "%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Delete "HKCU\Environment" /V "PCM_STYLE" /F )
```

Comment: Yes It Solved My Problem